# IBM App Connect Enterprise Could not locate JDBC Provider policy

Tags: jdbc, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus

I have created a JDBCProvider policy in an IBM App Connect Enterprise (ACE v11) in Windows called CLINIC
which is also the name of the database  I have a mapping Node where I'm trying to select from or insert into the Oracle Database
then i deployed the policy to the integration Node after i set credentials to the node

```
JDBCProviders
  CLINIC
    connectionUrlFormat='jdbc:oracle:thin:[user]/[password]@[serverName]:[portNumber]:[connectionUrlFormatAttr1]'
    connectionUrlFormatAttr1='XE'
    connectionUrlFormatAttr2=''
    connectionUrlFormatAttr3=''
    connectionUrlFormatAttr4=''
    connectionUrlFormatAttr5=''
    databaseName='CLINIC'
    databaseSchemaNames='useProvidedSchemaNames'
    databaseType='Oracle'
    databaseVersion='11.2'
    description=''
    environmentParms=''
    jarsURL='C:\\oraclexe\\app\\oracle\\product\11.2.0\server\\jdbc\\lib'
    jdbcProviderXASupport='TRUE'
    maxConnectionPoolSize='0'
    portNumber='1521'
    securityIdentity='mySecIdentity'
    serverName='localhost'
    type4DatasourceClassName='oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource'
    type4DriverClassName='oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
    useDeployedJars='FALSE'
```

then when i test the message flow i always getting this error:

```
Exception. BIP2230E: Error detected whilst processing a message in node &apos;MappSelect.Mapping&apos;. : C:\ci\product-build\WMB\src\DataFlowEngine\PluginInterface\jlinklib\ImbJniNode.cpp: 433: ImbJniNode::evaluate: ComIbmMSLMappingNode: MappSelect#FCMComposite_1_3
BIP6253E: Error in node: &apos;Mapping&apos;. Could not locate JDBC Provider policy &apos;&apos;XE&apos;&apos;, which was given for the data source name property for this node. : JDBCCommon.java: 575: JDBCDatabaseManager::constructor: :
```

so What am I missing? any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you did in your mapping node, but it should be one of the following :

1. You mentioned a wrong resource name. You have to mention CLINIC in your mapping node as a source
2. You did not restart the Integration Server after applying this configuration
3. https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-app-connect-enteprise-bip6253e-error-node-java-compute-could-not-locate-jdbc-provider-policy-mypoliciesmypolicy